# How to capitalize all letters inside quotation marks using sed?

Tags: regex, linux, unix, sed, capitalize

Can someone please explain to me how I can capitalize all the letters inside quotation marks using sed? For example "abcd1234" should become "ABCD1234". The length of the text inside the quotation marks is variable. I'm looking for an explanation not just the answer.

EDIT: I'm going to be using this on a text file. Suppose I have a text file like this:

Text that I don't want to capitalize and also "text that I want to capitalize"
And some other text and "some occasional quoted text and maybe numbers"
...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may depend on the version of `sed`, but in the one I have handy (GNU sed version 4.1.5), you can write `s/"[^"]*"/\U\0/`. For example, this Bash command:

```
sed 's/"[^"]*"/\U\0/g' <<< 'foo "bar" baz'
```

prints this:

```
foo "BAR" baz
```

There's not really much to explain except the `\U`, which is a special feature that causes the subsequent text in the replacement-string to be capitalized, up to either `\E` or end-of-string.

Comment: I have the same sed version and when I try this I get:"Missing name redirect"

Comment: @Arash, that might be a shell error: `<<<` is a bash "here-string". Are you using /bin/sh perhaps?

Comment: @ruakh, probably want `s///g` here, given the example in the question.

Comment: @glennjackman I just tried this: cat myfile.txt | sed s/"[^"]*"/\U\0/g and now I get -- Unmatched " --

Comment: You lost the sed command there: `sed 's/"[^"]\+"/\U&/g' myfile.txt` . "&" and "\0" are equivalent in the replacement string. If you want to save the changes back to the file, and if you use GNU sed, use `sed -i ...`

Comment: @glennjackman This works. Thanks. Is there a way I can use a pipe here? For example: myfile.txt | sed ... ? I'm using a change of pipes in my bash script and I want to be able to append this sed command to the end. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
echo abcd1234 | sed 's/\(.*\)/\U\1/'
```

small explanation to above command
(.*) will match all the characters so with escape sequence it will be (.*)
\U --To change to upper case..
suppose you want to change every thing to lower case use \L
then
\1 to paste first stored value.

Source: http://nixcraft.com/shell-scripting/15862-sed-convert-text-lower-upper-case.html

Comment: Where is the quotation mark specified here? Suppose I have a big text file with some quoted text. How do I capitalize only the quoted text? thanks.